# Put N mices in nearest holes

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

N mice are playing in the desert, when one of them notices some hawks flying in the sky. It alerts the other mice who now realize that the hawks are going to attack them very soon. They are scared and want to get inside holes to ensure their safety.

Mice and holes are placed on a straight line. There are m holes on this line. Each hole can accommodate only 1 mouse. A mouse can either stay at its position, or move one step right from x to x+1, or move one step left from x to x-1. Any of these movements takes 1 minute. 
Assign mice to holes so that the time required for all the mice to move inside the holes is minimized.

Example : Let N=3 and M=4 and mice be placed at [2,0,-4] and holes be at [3,1,2,-1] then here minimum time is 3.

How to solve it for given N ,M and array of holes and mices.

Comment: Can the mice only be in integer positions when starting?

Comment: @flawr Yeah they are only at integer coordinates

Comment: This was a hackerrank contest question. The contest is over now. Anyone?

Comment: Was an ongoing one, at that. This was from CodeSprint India 2014 Elimination Round 1, which began at 12:30 UTC that day. See https://www.hackerrank.com/rest/contests/csindia14-er1/challenges/mice-v2/download_pdf?language=English (note especially the URL) and https://www.hackerrank.com/csindia14-er1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you're allowed to put a mouse to a hole that is at most k steps away from it, then its an easy problem to solve.

Now if you can solve this for k you can solve this for every m > k.

So we can now binary  search on the range of allowed values for k and find the minimum allowable value